# Is it possible to use PECL extensions in HipHop?

Tags: php, pecl, hiphop

I have an application which uses rabbit mq broker and I have consumers written on php and use this extension http://pecl.php.net/package/amqp. I would like to compile these consumers using hiphop but amqp extension is not supported in hiphop. So the question is could I compile PECL extensions into hiphop?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You would have to manually write a HipHop extension in C++ to interface with the extension's functionality. Most likely the original PHP extension is of little use, if it merely wraps a C library anyway. See the answers on this thread for an explanation of what the differences between HipHop and PHP extensions are: https://groups.google.com/group/hiphop-php-dev/browse_thread/thread/51184984d948a77b

Answer (score 0):

I started the HHVM-AMQP project http://github.com/akalend/hhvm-amqp The base of the pecl/amqp is present, but exist the difference. See examples directory. It is developer version.