# Is hiphop compilation on the fly?

Tags: php, hiphop

Can I just upload the normal .php files to the server and will hiphop automatically compile the files on first request. Or do I have to compile the files before uploading to the server?

If I have a custom extension/module written in C, will it work with hiphop without any modification?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask two questions at once:

> Can I just upload the normal .php files to the server and will hiphop automatically compile the files on first request. Or do I have to compile the files before uploading to the server?

No, you need to compile them. Either before uploading or after uploading but in any case before the HTTP request.

> If I have a custom extension/module written in C, will it work with hiphop without any modification?

Not out of the box. This has been answered here:

- [Is it possible to use PECL extensions in HipHop?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10049049/367456)